# Add class using data attribute value while document ready

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to use data attributes for my HTML. I want to add a class while loading the page.

jQuery

```
var $this = $(this);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-load-animation]").each(function() {
        $this.hide();
        var cls = $this.attr("data-load-animation");
        console.log("console: "+cls);
        $this.addClass(cls);    
    })
})
```

Here is my [**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Cd4Sf/1/)

I need to add a class bounce for every element having this data attribute, I think... but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cd4Sf/2/ ?

Comment: Have a look to http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/Cd4Sf/3/

Comment: `$this` is not the same as `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `$this` reference, in your case it is referring the `window` object.

Instead you need to refer the current `[data-load-animation]` element, so define it within the `each()` loop

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-load-animation]").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.hide();
        var cls = $this.data("loadAnimation");
        console.log("console: " + cls);
        $this.addClass(cls);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misplacing  `$this` Try with the following, Where `$this` in the starting refers to current window

```
$("[data-load-animation]").each(function () {
    $this.hide();
    var cls = $(this).data("load-animation"); // Use data instead attr
    console.log("console: " + cls);
    $(this).addClass(cls); // Change to $(this) instead $this
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd4Sf/4/)